# Altbeacon library with android version 6

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I'm updating the altbeacon library to the latest 2.9.1 but I don't get any beacon when I range for it, this is using android 6.0.1.

```
public class BeaconService extends IntentService implements BeaconConsumer {
    private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;
    private static ArrayList<Beacon> beaconsList=new ArrayList<Beacon>();
    private Region region=new Region("rid", null, null, null);
    private static final String LOGTAG = "BeaconService";


/**
 * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
 */
public BeaconService() {
    super(Constants.BEACON_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    try {
        mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
             Intent localIntent =new Intent(Constants.BEACON_ACTION);
             beaconsList.clear();
             beaconsList.addAll(beacons);
             Collections.sort(beaconsList,new Comparator<Beacon>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Beacon lhs, Beacon rhs) {
                        return Double.compare(lhs.getDistance(), rhs.getDistance());
                    }
             });
             localIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.BEACON_LIST,beaconsList);
             LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(BeaconService.this).sendBroadcast(localIntent);

            }
        });
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG,"Error BeaconService",e);
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    mBeaconManager.bind(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
}

/**
 * Stop Scanning
 */
public void stopRanging(){
    try {
        mBeaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG,"Error BeaconService - StopRanging",e);
    }
}

/**
 * Start Scanning
 */
public void startRanging(){
    try {
        mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG,"Error BeaconService - StartRanging",e);
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new LocalBinder();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BeaconService getService() {
        return BeaconService.this;
    }
}
```

I did try changing to monitoring and the same result, also I did try adding more layouts but I don't get any beacons on the list

Comment: Are you saying this same code worked with an earlier Library version that 2.9.1?  Does onBeaconServiceConnect () get called?

Comment: yeah I did fix it by adding the request permission at runtime, looks like that is the only way that it works

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need to add the permission at runtime, I did fix it by doing this

```
@Override
public void initialize(final CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "initialize");
    context = webView.getContext();
    beaconServiceIntent = new Intent(context, BeaconService.class);
    context.bindService(beaconServiceIntent, serviceBeaconConnection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    BeaconReceiver beaconReciever = new BeaconReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Constants.BEACON_ACTION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(beaconReciever, intentFilter);
    mainActiviy = (Activity) context;
    checkPermission();
}    


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void checkPermission() {
    if(this.mainActiviy.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(((Activity)context));
        builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
        builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect beacons.");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                mainActiviy.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```